# XCode 9.3 breaks playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I just upgraded from XCode 9.2 to XCode 9.3. 
Since then my playground is very unresponsive/slow, animations play at unexpected times and UIKit elements are not properly layouted anymore.

**Are there any known issues and/or fixes that I can apply?**

Comment: Try moving any UI related code to the additional sources folder so it is compiled ahead of time.

Comment: try removing the derived data. It helped solves this issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same issue and there was no way around it. People filed bugs as far back as April 8th.

Best solution is to download Xcode 9.4 Beta from [Apple Developer Page](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

This worked for me and CPU usage is low and Xcode doesn't crash on playgrounds anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Playgrounds have been buggy all along but 9.3 takes it to another level. Have you noticed a “diagnosticd” process taking up much of the cpu while running playgrounds? I suspect that this may be in part responsible for the lack of performance.  Not much to do until Apple gets their act together (if ever)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9.3.1 has just been released (10 May 2018) and is supposed to fix 'an issue that caused Xcode to slow down when editing a playground'.

Comment: 9.3.1 didn't fix issue for me

Answer (score 0):

**Kill "homed"**

My experience is that `homed` is going nuts, hogging the CPU.

Without quitting the Playground app, you can go into `Activity Monitor` (`Applications > Utitlities > Activity Monitor`) and sort by %CPU, you might see Process Name `homed` taking a large CPU load.  Double clicking on `homed` and selecting `Quit` does not seem to harm the workings of the playground.

If you still encounter problems, you could close the Playground app, and use the same process to force quit `com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`, although doing that requires a lengthy process when you restart your Playground.